# how to execute INSERT INTO statement right after CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE in Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to populate a newly created table with some data right after its creation, like I would do in a regular DBMS like MySQL or PostgreSQL.

However, it complaints about the INSERT token after the CREATE OR REPLACE statement even if I have semicolons to separate statements.

This is what I want to execute:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `foo.bar.months` (text STRING, number INT64);
INSERT INTO `foo.bar.months` (text, number) VALUES ('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr', 4), ('May', 5), ('Jun', 6), ('Jul', 7), ('Aug', 8), ('Sep', 9), ('Oct', 10), ('Nov', 11), ('Dec', 12);
```

If I comment the second statement and execute the first and, then, do the opposite (comment the first statement and uncomment the second one and execute it), it works. It creates the table and, then, populates it. Just... I want to do it all in one pass.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an AS SELECT clause with CREATE TABLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `foo.bar.months` AS
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(
  ARRAY<STRUCT<text STRING, number INT64>>[
    ('Jan', 1), ('Feb', 2), ('Mar', 3), ('Apr', 4),
    ('May', 5), ('Jun', 6), ('Jul', 7), ('Aug', 8),
    ('Sep', 9), ('Oct', 10), ('Nov', 11), ('Dec', 12)]);
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Multiple queries are not supported in the WebUI.

What you can do is paste the contents. Then highlight each one of the statement and hit Run selected. And you need to do this multiple times.

[image]